# Is it possible to use webpack with bower and angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I have an angular app I would like include all my scripts that I need in 1 or 2 bundles file
But I want to minify them to 1 or 2 bundle file so the browser will be faster when moving between the pages or loading.

All my external modules and libraries are located in bower components or in separate vendor folder

My question is how can I use webpack for this minifying task?
The app will run on local machine without internet connection

Comment: it's a bit hard to understand what you are asking, but generally, if you are including all your scripts on every "page" in your angularjs app, you probably are doing something wrong.  Angularjs is a **Single Page Application** framework, it shouldn't have multiple pages.  Not sure webpack would help if your app isn't structured properly......

Comment: It s a 3 different app   with index for each of then.  I just want a minify all the scripts per each app

Comment: if it's 3 different apps, then how would bundling the scripts together help?  why not just limit each app to only downloading the scripts that belong to that app, and not the ones that belong to the other apps?  as I said, it's really unclear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Let's say 1 app only